# How to compare two data frames in R with nested loops

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, nested

```
for(i in as.vector(as.matrix(TargetLength))) {
  for(j in as.vector(as.matrix(AlignmentBlockLength))) {
    if(c(i) == c(j)) {
      print("alignment")
    }
  }
}
```

How do I implement this nested for loop in R? Or is there another way to compare each value in the first data frame with each value in the second data frame without using a nested loop?

Comment: You can use `outer` to do the comparison `outer(v1, v2, "==")`.  It returns a logical vector which would be more useful.  `v1` and `v2` are the vectors.  Also, if `TargetLength` and `AlignmentBlockLength` are data.frames, use `unlist(TargetLength)` instead of `as.vector(as.matrix`

Comment: Would you use outer along with the nested loop or on its own?

Comment: In the code I meant `v1 <- as.vector(as.matrix(TargetLength))` and `v2 <- as.vector(as.matrix(AlignmentBlockLength))`  It is used separately without any nested loops

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that compares value in the first data frame with the second dataframe. But there is a simpler way, however, I give you both solutions.

```
### Solution 1
compare <- function(df1,df2){
  n = nrow(df1); p = ncol(df1)
  result = matrix(NA,nrow = n, ncol = p)
  for(j in seq_len(p)){
    for(i in seq_len(n)){
      result[i,j] <- df1[i,j] == df2[i,j]
    }
  }
  print(result)
}


A = data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),2,3,T))
B =  data.frame(10+matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),2,3,T))

compare(A,A)
compare(A,B)

### Solution 2
A == B
#as.vector(A == B)
        X1    X2    X3
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```